# Как очень просто сохранить большое количество массивов и переменных в бинарный файл?

Tags: c++, c++11

Всем привет, мне нужно 2-два примера первый с массивными а второй с переменными.

Или хотя бы один пример, дальше я сам додумаю.

На данный момент мне удалось сохранить данный только одной переменной

```
string path = "1.bin";

int x = 2147483647;

// Прочитать данные

ifstream loading;
loading.open(path);

while (loading.read((char*)& x, sizeof(x)))
{
    cout << x << endl;
}

loading.close();


// Сохранить данные
ofstream save;
save.open(path, ofstream::app);

save.write((char*)& x, sizeof(x));

save.close();
```

Comment: очень просто откройте файл в бинарном режиме и очень просто сохраняйте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loading.open(path,std::ios::binary);

save.open(path, ofstream::app bitor std::ios::binary);

int arr[N];
save.write((char*)arr, sizeof(int)*N);
```

Comment: А для чего нужно писать std::ios::binary ?

Comment: Поток текстовый очень сложный, он фильтрует символы.

Comment: И можно еще пример используя class
например у меня есть такой class `Z(511, 4214, 215, 2512, 125);`
Это и за template он так выглядит 
`template <typename T1, .......>Z(T1 i, T2 a, T3 x, T4 y, T5 k)`

Comment: Всё тоже самое `read/write(..,sizeof(Z<..>))`.

Comment: Ок буду пробовать, спасибо

Comment: Еще вопрос что такое bit_or, просто мне пишет ошибку нету скобок

Comment: Битовое сложение опций : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bit_or

Comment: `std::bit_or` или `|`

Comment: легче один символ написать '|' чем  bit_or.   Не нужны лишные "мудрости "

Comment: Вот так?
`save.open(path, ofstream::app | std::ios::binary);`
Или лучше так `save.open(path, ofstream::app, std::ios::binary);`

Просто не понимаю в чем разница

Comment: @AlexGlebe `bit_or` -> `bitor`. Хотя `|` мне тоже нравится больше.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Перешёл на буквы, так как сишный вариант типа `x|y&&!x||~y` - не очень переваривается.